# Searching for numbers bigger than 1000 in bash

Tags: bash, shell, files

I'm a bash begginer and I want to solve the next problem:
Find all the files in a directory received as command line argument that contain numbers greater than 1000. If the command line doesn't contain any arguments, display a message and exit.

Firstly I wanted to check only if there is a number equal to 1000, because I don't know how to check if it's bigger using grep. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $0 -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No arguments"
    exit 0
fi

for filename in $1
do
    if [ -f filename ]
    then
        if grep -q "1000" $filename
            echo $filename
        fi
    fi
done
```

And it raises some errors on line 3 and 15 andI don't know why.

Can somebody help me,please?

UPDATED CODE:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No arguments"
    exit 0
fi

for filename in $1
do
    if [ -f filename ]
    then
        if grep -q "1000" $filename
        then
            echo $filename
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Try [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: `$0` is not an integer, it represents the shell, so it's equal to `bash`. `-eq` expects an integer, hence the error.

Comment: And you are missing a `then` in your second `if`.

Comment: When asking questions about an error, it is important that you actually include the error! Telling us "it raises some errors" doesn't really give us much information :) Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I've changed but now I have error on line 3:unary operator expected

Comment: It should check for a number greater than 1000 inside the file, not in the name

Comment: `$1` has to be an integer. If nothing is passed, then the comparison fails. You have to check if  `$1` is empty and if it's an integer `[[ -z $1 ]] && echo "empty" && exit` and then `[[ ! $1 =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]] && echo "not integer" && exit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$0` expands to the name of the script, not the command line arguments.

[3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters)

If you want to check if there are no command line arguments you can use:

```
if (($#==0)); then
    echo "No arguments" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

`$#` will expand to the number of command line arguments.   Also note we are redirecting the error to stderr and exiting with a code of 1 rather than 0.  0 typically means success where non-zero means error.

`$1` will only ever be a single option so there is no need to loop over it.  Also, it seems like your script is only supposed to receive a single **directory** as an argument, and while this is technically a file it will fail the `-f` test.

`grep -q "1000" $filename` will search for the presence of `1000` within the file and won't find any numbers greater than 1000 unless they also literally contain 1000 (ie: `101000`).

You could use a recursive grep on the directory to perform a regex search to look for numbers 1000 or greater:

```
grep -rE '[1-9][0-9]{3,}' "$1"
```

This will print the filenames and match but if you want to only print the filename you can do:

```
grep -rEl '[1-9][0-9]{3,}' "$1"
```

Comment: `grep -l` to print just the filenames? at least with GNU grep

Comment: @ilkkachu: Thanks, seems that option is available on BSD and solaris grep as well.